# Reverting a remote git repo after a reset done locally

Tags: git

How does one revert a remote git repo after a reset done locally?

We had accidentally pushed changes to master branch. I've reverted the code in the local branch to the last good commit. Now, I am trying to update the remote repo so that it is also at the last commit -- future pulls and clones are at the last good commit, but and running into errors.

Here is what I've tried:

```
git reset --hard <last-good-commit-hash>
```

which worked fine

Then, to update the remote repo,

```
git push origin master
```

Which gave me:

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'host:/srv/git/cms'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes before pushing again.  See the 'Note about
fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

Then, I tried:

```
git push --force origin master

Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/master (you should pull first)
To host:/srv/git/cms
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'host:/srv/git/cms'
```

If I do a pull, I am back to the bad commits.

Comment: What kind of server is this you're pushing to?  I'm pretty sure there are configuration options to prevent forced pushes, and these may be what's stopping you.

Comment: May pull a specific older version?

Comment: There is a hook on server to reject your non-ff commit. You should contact the server admin to remove that hook.

Comment: @vergenzt: The server I'm pushing to houses the remote git repo. It is a redhat box.

Comment: If you have access to that server, check your `/srv/git/cms/hooks` directory, delete the `post-receive` hook.

Comment: @J-16 SDiZ & @vergenzt: Thanks. I have a `post-receive.sample` with all lines commented out in `/srv/git/cms/hooks` ... is this the file you're referring to?

Comment: no, that is just a sample.  Check your `config` file on server, does it have `denyNonFastForwards=true`?  If yes, do `git config receive.denyNonFastForwards false`

Comment: It does! Any downside to setting it to `false`?

Comment: @J-16 SDiZ, thanks, that helped fix this. If you'd like, go ahead and put it in an answer, and I'll gladly and gratefully accept (_:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your config file on server, does it have `denyNonFastForwards=true`?

If yes, do this:

```
git config receive.denyNonFastForwards false
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `git reset <commit>` try

```
git revert <commit>
git push origin master
```